# Adding Hyphen (-) in the Path Segment causes issues with response when using Odata (4.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'd like to add hyphen (-) in the path segment of the URL. I'm working with OData libraries (4.0).

My URL https//StackOverFlow/Forums/v1/Question-Answers

Sample response:
{
"name": "John Smith", //level 1
"age": 30,
"address": {
"street": "123 Main St", // level 2
"city": "Anytown",
"state": "CA",
"zip": "12345",
"country": "USA",
"coordinates": {    // level 3
"latitude": 37.1234,
"longitude": -122.4321
}
}
}

If I have the path segment "Question-Answers", then the response would not have Coordinates shown at all. In other words, it will always show until level 2. However, I change it to "QuestionAnswers" , then I see all the objects in the response including Coordinates.

I don't see any exceptions being thrown.

Also, in the modelBuilder, I'm setting maxDepth as 3.

```
    // Summary:
    //     Sets Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder.SelectExpandType of all properties with maximum
    //     depth of expand result of this structural type.
    public StructuralTypeConfiguration<TStructuralType> Expand(SelectExpandType expandType, int maxDepth);
```

Looking for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

First you should verify your hyphen problem. Try to remove the hyphen from the path segment. If the problem disappears, you can remove the MaxDepth from your problem. I think that will happen.

The MaxLevel in combination with 3 is a strong indicator for a OData issue of Microsoft libs.

Please take a look at:

- https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2028
- https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/272
- https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/discussions/603

You could solve the problem with applying the **Contained** attribute in your data structure or adding additional **EntitySets** of substructures to your model. This is an old unresolved issue in the OData libs.